# GPU vs CPU programming: inconsistencies in processing times

Tags: android, c++, opencv, opencl

I'm currently working on image tracking: thanks to a camera I'm tracking finger touches that interact with an Android system. Image processing is done on a GPU with OpenCL: I convert the camera output into black and white frames in order to get the spots in white. The processing time is 65ms with this method.
Since my objective is to make the program smoother, I've performed the same operations on a CPU with an OpenCV method. That gives a processing time of 115ms. The problem is that the program feels more reactive, faster with the OpenCV method and I don't understand how the processing time can be longer in that case: it seems contradictory to me.
For the measurement, I proceed like this:

```
start= clock();
finish = clock();
double time =((double)finish -start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
std::cout<<"process time : "<< time<<std::endl;
```

here is my code:

```
static cv::Mat              original_Right,binary_Right;
static cv::Mat              original_Left, binary_Left;
int                 width, height;
clock_t                 start,finish;
double time = 0.0;

width = (int) this->camera_Right.getCapture().get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
height = (int) this->camera_Right.getCapture().get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
original_Right.create(height, width, CV_8UC3);


//--------------------------- Camera 2 ---------------------------------
int width_2 = (int) this->camera_Left.getCapture().get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
int height_2 = (int) this->camera_Left.getCapture().get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
original_Left.create(height_2, width_2, CV_8UC3);


binary_Right.create(height, width, CV_32F); // FOR GPU
binary_Left.create(height_2, width_2, CV_32F); // FOR GPU
//binary_Right.create(height, width, CV_8UC1); // FOR CPU
//binary_Left.create(height_2, width_2, CV_8UC1); // FOR CPU

Core::running_ = true;


//------------------------------------ SET UP THE GPU -----------------------------------------
cl_context              context;
cl_context_properties   properties [3];
cl_kernel               kernel;
cl_command_queue        command_queue;
cl_program              program;
cl_int                  err;
cl_uint                 num_of_platforms=0;
cl_platform_id          platform_id;
cl_device_id            device_id;
cl_uint                 num_of_devices=0;
cl_mem                  input, output;

size_t                  global;

int                     data_size =height*width*3;


//load opencl source
FILE *fp;
char fileName[] = "./helloTedKrissV2.cl";
char *source_str;

 //Load the source code containing the kernel
fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
if (!fp) {
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
exit(1);
}
source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
global = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
fclose(fp);


//retreives a list of platforms available
if(clGetPlatformIDs(1,&platform_id, &num_of_platforms)!=CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<"unable to get a platform_id"<<std::endl;
};

// to get a supported GPU device
if(clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,1,&device_id, &num_of_devices)!= CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<"unable to get a device_id"<<std::endl;      
};

//context properties list - must be terminated with 0
properties[0]=CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM;
properties[1]=(cl_context_properties) platform_id;
properties[2]=0;

// create a context with the gpu device
context = clCreateContext(properties,1,&device_id,NULL,NULL,&err);

//create command queue using the context and device
command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,device_id,0,&err);

//create a program from the kernel source code
program= clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,(const char **) &source_str, NULL,&err);

// compile the program
if(clBuildProgram(program,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)!=CL_SUCCESS){
    size_t length;
    std::cout<<"Error building program"<<std::endl;
    char buffer[4096];
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,device_id,CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer),buffer,&length);
    std::cout<< buffer <<std::endl;
}

//specify which kernel from the program to execute
kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"imageProcessing",&err);




while (this->isRunning() == true) { 

    start= clock(); //--------------------- START----------------------

    //----------------------FRAME---------------------
    this->camera_Right.readFrame(original_Right);
    if (original_Right.empty() == true ) {
        std::cerr << "[Core/Error] Original  frame is empty." << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    this->camera_Left.readFrame(original_Left);
    if (original_Left.empty() == true ) {
        std::cerr << "[Core/Error] Original 2  frame is empty." << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    //----------------------FRAME---------------------



  //------------------------------------------------IMP GPU ------------------------------------------------------

    input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR  , sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size,NULL,NULL);
    output =clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE   | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*data_size/3,NULL,NULL);

   if(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,input,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size, original_Right.data ,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};

    //set the argument list for the kernel command
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    global = data_size  ;
    //enqueue the kernel command for execution
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    //copy the results from out of the  output buffer
    if(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,output,CL_TRUE ,0,sizeof(float)*data_size/3,binary_Right.data,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};

    clReleaseMemObject(input);
    clReleaseMemObject(output);

    //------------------------------------------------IMP GPU ------------------------------------------------------

    input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR  , sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size,NULL,NULL);
    output =clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE   | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(float)*data_size/3,NULL,NULL);

   if(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,input,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size, original_Left.data ,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};

    //set the argument list for the kernel command
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    global = data_size  ;
    //enqueue the kernel command for execution
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    //copy the results from out of the  output buffer
    if(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,output,CL_TRUE ,0,sizeof(float)*data_size/3,binary_Left.data,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};

   clReleaseMemObject(input);
   clReleaseMemObject(output);

    //------------------------------------------------IMP GPU ------------------------------------------------------

  // CPU METHOD
  // adok::processing::doImageProcessing(original_Right, binary_Right);
  // adok::processing::doImageProcessing(original_Left, binary_Left);

    //-------------------------------------------------------------- TRACKING ------------------------------------------------------

adok::tracking::doFingerContoursTracking(binary_Right,binary_Left, this->fingerContours, this->perspective_Right,this->perspective_Left, this->distortion_Right,this->distortion_Left, this);

    //------------------------------------------- TRACKING -----------------------------------------

 //------------------------------SEND COORDINATES TO ANDROID BOARD--------------------
if (getSideRight() && !getSideLeft() ) {
        std::cout<<"RIGHT : "<<std::endl;
        this->uart_.sendAll(this->fingerContours, this->perspective_Right.getPerspectiveMatrix(), RIGHT);
    }else if (!getSideRight() && getSideLeft() ){
        std::cout<<"LEFT : "<<std::endl;
        this->uart_.sendAll(this->fingerContours, this->perspective_Left.getPerspectiveMatrix(), LEFT);
    }else if (getSideRight() && getSideLeft() ){
        std::cout<<"RIGHT & LEFT : "<<std::endl;
        this->uart_.sendAll(this->fingerContours, this->perspective_Right.getPerspectiveMatrix(), this->perspective_Left.getPerspectiveMatrix());

    }

this->setSideRight(0);
this->setSideLeft(0);

finish = clock();
time =(double)(finish - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
std::cout << "Time: " << time << std::endl; // ------------END-----------

}
clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
clReleaseProgram(program);
clReleaseKernel(kernel);
clReleaseContext(context);
this->stop();
```

}

There is also something strange, when I'm on CPU the time for grabbing a frame is 5ms while on GPU it's 15ms and i don't know why it increases.

And I'm working on an android xu4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer!! I found out why it feels halting: it's because the time for grabbing a frame passes from 5ms to 15ms. It might be because I create a buffer which decreases the bandwidth. The programming on GPU is faster than on CPU but it affects the image/sec.
AND the reason of this is because I'm doing this twice (for each camera) :

```
    if(clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,input,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size, original_Right.data ,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};
    //set the argument list for the kernel command
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    global = data_size  ;
    //enqueue the kernel command for execution
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
    clFinish(command_queue);
    //copy the results from out of the  output buffer
    if(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue,output,CL_TRUE ,0,sizeof(unsigned char)*data_size,original_Right.data,0,NULL,NULL )!= CL_SUCCESS){};
```

Answer (score 3):

In `GPU` calculation there sometime it may take much time than `CPU` calculation. Because, for `GPU` calculation the main process send data to `GPU` memory and after mathematical calculation the `GPU` sends back the data to `CPU`. So, data transfer and receive back to `CPU` takes time. If the calculated buffer size is bigger and transfer time is bigger it can take more time in `GPU` calculation. `CUDNN` library along with `GPU` processor makes it many times faster. So, if your program is not using `CUDNN` it may be slower.

Comment: I'm working with openCL, so i suppose that i can't use CUDNN library. But this doesn't explain why i measure a time lower  and in real it feels halting.

Comment: what is your frame dimension?

Comment: see this http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Poor-OpenCL-performance-td7584466.html

Comment: 640*480
I understand that the transfers affect the time of process but it should appear on the time I measure. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try use event to see how long it takes to write the data and how long it takes to process it.
And in general use clFinish is not a good idea.  When you get the event from Enqueue command and pass it to Read Data, the read data will happen at once when process finished.
Another problem is you don't have to recreate the buffer object every time, as far as you have same data size, you may create it once and keep reuse it.